# C# PCL alternative for System.Diagnostics.Stacktrace

Tags: c#, debugging, portable-class-library

First off, I know there's another question with this exact title, but 1) there is no resolution to the question, and I can see the op has asked the same question on other forums, which also don't have an accepted answers.  2) I think the use case for Stacktrace may be different in my case.  Much like the other poster, I'm trying to implementing some logging on a Windows 8.1 application.  We have a method:

```
private string GetSource()
    {
        var output = "";
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        var method = stackTrace.GetFrame(2).GetMethod();
        output = $"{method.ReflectedType.Namespace} {method.ReflectedType.Name} {method.Name}";
        return output;
    }
```

that we use in our back-end services.  We use this to find out who and what method called our telemetry/logging event.  I can see that others had recommended Environment.Stacktrace, but as some commenters had noted, StackTrace is not available in the Environment class with PCL support.  My guess is that there could be some convoluted method using reflection to achieve this goal.  If that's the case, then an example of how it would be done would be great along with any other recommended solutions.